# rails, prototype, preload remote called pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using periodic_remote_call and it updates a div with pictures.

How Can I get these pictures to be preloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know hwether you still need the information, but you can indeed make a dynamic piece of JavaScript containing the ids, which you can use for your preload. Your View would contain something like this (assuming that `@photo_ids` is the Ruby array):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var photo_ids = new Array(%< @photo_ids.join(", ") %>);
</script>
```

Now you can loop your `photos_id` in JavaScript to preload the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myimage = new Image;
myimage.src = "/images/myimage.jpg";
```

Comment: SO if I wanted  to loop over an array of ids and preload each one on the page how could I do this because the ids are stored as ruby variables.